# Create PDF from a very wide page with PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I have a very wide, about 2000-3000px, page which I want to print to PDF using PhantomJS. No matter how wide I set the viewport the page size stays the same, while the content goes way out of the actual print area. This sounds right to me. But is there a way to print very wide pages correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try playing around with zoomFactor?

Answer (score 0):

Use the paperSize property to increase the size of the page that phantomjs will print to.

Comment: I tried various settings, including paperSize, but nothing worked. We ditched the PhantomJS solution in the meantime.

Comment: I know it does take a bit of work to get it working. I was able to get it done though. Here is my solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22017746/while-rendering-webpage-to-pdf-using-phantomjs-how-can-i-auto-adjust-my-viewpor