# Print output split out to multiple pages when using phantomjs to print a long webpage

Tags: pdf, printing, phantomjs, html

I have been able to print a webpage to different sizes of a single pdf. There is a way to assign the width and height of the single page. But if my browser window is long with lets say 10000 rows of data, I want it to display split up into multiple pages. Is that possible using this utility?

Comment: can you provide some of your code ?

Comment: Yeah.. look through my other question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22017746/while-rendering-webpage-to-pdf-using-phantomjs-how-can-i-auto-adjust-my-viewpor/22031421#22031421

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a non issue. When I increased the browser viewport heigh to something way more than what I had specified for the pdf page dimensions, it did cut it up into multiple pages. Thank God!